# Trying to assign a response.data value to a variable in react and the value doesnt pass well

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Im building an AuthContext in react to handle login, i connect it to a django backend where i validate the user and then i get an authorization token

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const AuthContext = createContext();


  export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  
    const login = async (username, password) => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/token/', {
          username,
          password
        });
        console.log('Response data:', response.data);
        const { token: responseToken } = response.data;
        setToken(responseToken);
    
        console.log('Token loaded:', responseToken);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error en el inicio de sesión:', error);
      }
    };    
  
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('Token actual value:', token); 
    }, [token]);
  
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token, login }}>
        {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  };
```

From my backend i get the expected answer, an status 200 with the token that i expect, but after assign the response.data to responseToken, in the next log it shows that is undefined. Here is the output in the navigator console:

[console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqypd.png)

Tried to change the variable names to check if there is a conflict between those declared there, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console log shows that response data has two properties `refresh` & `access`. But you are trying to get a property called `token`, which does not exist (or at least it's not visible in your screenshot).

```
const { access: responseToken } = response.data;
```

This should help. (if `access` is the one you actually need)